# How to set permissions on virtual network directory when application pool uses LOCALSYSTEM?

Tags: iis, asp.net

I have a Windows 10 web server development machine (let's call it: "DEVELOPMENTMACHINE") where the application pool uses LOCALSYSTEM. Without using LOCALSYSTEM, the Windows text-to-speech wouldn't work on some voices.

Now I'm trying to set up a virtual directory pointing to a directory on another machine that is shared, via a reference like "\\OTHERMACHINE\ShareName". This directory, which also is a web server directory on that machine, has the user names and permissions for "IUSR" and "IIS_IUSRS(OTHERMACHINE\IIS_IUSRS)" set up, as well as being readable and writable as a normal shared directory. However, when I run the development website on DEVELOPMENTMACHINE, it can't access the "\\OTHERMACHINE\ShareName" directory. I need the DEVELOPMENTMACHINE web server code (ASP.NET) to be able to read and write to that share, just like it does to its local directory. What do I need to set up to make this work?

Comment: The description you gave is a clear indicator that you should split the functionalities into multiple processes (like web app on IIS and Windows service app running under Local System), because running a web app under such a powerful account is insane. Run the web app under a suitable domain account and then you can set remote file share permissions accordingly.

Comment: Great idea. I didn't know about services. This seems to be a good start: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/introduction-to-windows-service-applications.

Comment: I revised to use a Windows service, and change the application pool to use the ApplicationPoolIdentity, but I still don't know how to set up the permissions.  Also, a virtual directory that points to a directory on the same disk now also is unable to access the virtual directory.

Comment: I see that the none-virtual web directory has a permission object name that is the same as the application pool/website, and the virtual directory target does not, and in trying to create on with the application pool name, it doesn't know the object name. I left it as pass-through authentication in creating the virtual directories.  I tried also using my Microsoft login account, but that didn't work either. What am I missing?

Comment: For the virtual directory which is a local directory, setting up user "IIS AppPool\(appPoolName)" worked.  I then tried adding this permission to the virtual directory which is on another machine, but it still results in an insufficient permissions error. Curiously, instead of the app pool name, the permissions is listed as an "Unknown User".